# How to enter a new line in UITextView in IB

Tags: uitextview, newline

I'm just trying to enter some default text in a UITextView. There are a few paragraphs, and I wanted to separate the paragraphs with a new line. However, when I press enter, it just completes the entry of the data.

How can I enter a new line when creating the default text for a UITextView in the Interface Builder?

Comment: Another way is using code directly, in a string \n go to a new line

Answer (score 14):

It is very easy, you have to write your paragraph and then push SHIFT+ALT+ENTER at the same time when you want a new line.

It also works with UILabels.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape *special* keys being interpreted by the text system by entering `^-Q` (control-Q) first. That works for **return**, **tab** etc. in just about all places on OS X.